# Cannot use PSQLException.class in @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I am getting this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ix_auth_username"
  Detail: Key (username, authority)=(mike, ROLE_USER) already exists.
```

And this is how I try to handle this exception:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler({IllegalArgumentException.class, PSQLException.class})
    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleIllegalArgumentException(HttpServletRequest request, IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        HttpStatus status;
        switch (exception.getClass().getName()) {
            case "IllegalArgumentException":
                status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
                break;
            default:
                status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
                break;
        }
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(status, LocalDateTime.now(), exception.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errorResponse);
    }
}
```

But IntelliJ gives me this error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'PSQLException'

Why? PostgreSQL works fine for me. This is how I use the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace

```xml
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

with

```xml
<version>42.5.4</version>
```

That should make it work.